# Probability of rolling a 6 in 3 rolls of a balanced die.

Tags: probability

I'm having troubles solving this question due to $2$ possible conclusions that I've found and come up with.

One method of approaching the problem is by finding the probability of not getting a $6$, $3$ times and subtracting it from the sample space or $100\%$. (This is the solution that naturally makes sense to me).

Given that $216$ is the total possible outcomes of rolling 3die 6x6x6

$P$(of rolling a $6$) $= 1- (5/6)^3  = 91/216$

The other possible solution is using binomial distribution
That is $P$(Getting a $6$) $= {3 \choose 1} \cdot (1/6) \cdot (5/6)^2  = 75/216$

Which is the correct solution and why?

Comment: Those two methods compute different things.  The first computes the probability of getting at least one $6$, the second computes the probability of getting exactly one $6$.